# Why does creation of the following prepared statements fail?

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement

In psql and postgresql, why does creation of the following prepared statements fail? Thanks.

```
mytestdb=# PREPARE fooplan (INT, VARCHAR(80)) AS
    CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, name VARCHAR(80));  PREPARE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 2:     CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, name VARCHAR(80));
```

and

```
mytestdb=# PREPARE fooplan (INT, VARCHAR(80)) AS
    CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, name VARCHAR(80)); INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2); PREPARE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 2:     CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, name VARCHAR(80));
            ^
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
LINE 1: INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2);
                               ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only DML commands can be used in a prepared statement. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html)

> Any `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `VALUES` statement.

The DDL command `CREATE TABLE` is not allowed.

And only a single statement. The `INSERT` in your second example is not part of the prepared statement, but a second, separate, independent statement.